# How to re-order the "Look Up" button when holding to select text?

Tags: iphone, ios, accessibility

I am a big-time user of the [Look Up](https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-use-iphone-dictionary/) functionality of the iPhone, added in iOS 11.

However, I don't like that I have to jump through hoops to get to the "Look Up" button when I hold to select the text, and then click on it. As you can see in this [screen recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIUqN.jpg), in iOS 16 at least, the picker displays the "Copy", "Select All", and "Find Selection" buttons in the first view. To see the "Look Up" button, you have to click on the right arrow icon to get to the second view.

Is there any setting for re-ordering the buttons, such that the "Look Up" button appears in the first view?

[image: Hold to Select in iOS 16]

Answer (score 4):

No there is no option for this at the moment.

You can leave feedback to Apple at https://apple.com/feedback or https://feedbackassistant.apple.com.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up contacting Apple to suggest this as a feature request.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is available at least in some apps as default or if you use phone horizontally.

You can access "Look Up" without hoops in  Mail, StackOverflow app etc. In Books and Safari it is available if you have phone horizontally.

[image]